# Como ler texto de uma caixa de texto de um documento Word via C#

Tags: c#, console, microsoft-word

Estou utilizando o Interop para manipular um word, através de uma console application.

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

Consigo extrair o array de bytes, salvar como Pdf, como imagem etc, porém uma coisa relativamente simples que estou precisando ainda não consegui.

Preciso dar um replace em determinado texto do documento, que está dentro de uma caixa de texto, porém não sei como fazer isso.

A partir da variavel `_documentoWord` consigo acessar os elementos, porém nas minhas tentativas ainda não deu certo.

```
_aplicativoWord = new Word.Application() {Visible = false};
_documentoWord = _aplicativoWord.Documents.Open(caminho);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri uma maneira que vai me atender:

```
    public static void SearchTextBox(string name, string newContent)
    {
        _documentoWord.Content.ShapeRange.Ungroup();

        foreach (Word.Shape i in _documentoWord.Content.ShapeRange)
        {
            if (i.AlternativeText.IndexOf(name) != -1)
            {
                i.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Primeiro desagrupei tudo que poderia estar agrupado. Depois varri os shapes do documento. Se o texto alternativo for igual ao texto que estou procurando eu entro no TextFrame.TextRange.Text e modifico o texto, apagando-o.